# How to set row delimiter for pandas to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to use a different row delimiter than "\n" with pandas to_csv(). Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Did you try the `line_terminator` parameter?

Comment: @khelwood yes that works! Thanks!